# Remote desktop idle time

Tags: c#, desktop

We have an application that requires to be continously run but it can't run as a service so we run it in Windows 2003 console session. After migration to Windows 2008 and with the session 0 isolation, the GPO causes the session to teminate after the session is idle for 30 minutes.

I wrote a little C# application to simulate key press using sendkeys.send and sendwait but the remote desktop session still gets connected. Any source code or idea to keep the session permentantly active other than changing the GPO as this isn't possible for the time being?

Comment: I must admit, I am curious, why are you not able to run this application as a service?

Comment: Uh, that smells... you should really find a better way to run your application. In any case, have you tried running it through Task Scheduler (can be set to be started on computer startup)?

Comment: That application is provided by third party vendor and it will take them few months to change the application to run as a service.

Comment: The application processes real time transactions so task scheduler isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are prob two options you could look at for obtaining the desired effect.

1) SrvAny.exe - this is a tool provided by Microsoft, that will take any exe and run it from the services control panel.  While there is no version that officially supports server 2008, the version that works on server 2003 works just fine.  I've used it to run dropbox has a service in the past.

Here is a tutorial that does something similar with dropbox [Dropbox as a service on server 2008](http://blog.dreamfactory.se/2011/03/11/installing-dropbox-as-a-service-on-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-x64/)

2) Write a stub application that will run as a service and do nothing more than launch the exe from the vendor.

I realize this is not what you asked persay, but it would give you the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Eventually all workarounds were rejected so it was decided to modify the domain GPO.